# sed search replace regexp pattern to replace repeated strings in paths

Tags: linux, sed

I'm having some trouble using `sed` to replace a particular repeated portion of a file path, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to work.

For example, say I have a list of file paths:

**input.txt**

```
gs://example-bucket/H20/H20AC0010001999B-01.jpg
gs://example-bucket/H20/H20AC0010001999B-02.jpg
gs://example-bucket/H20/H20AC0010001999B-03.jpg
```

And I want to keep the folder structure but remove the same reference in the filename itself:

**ideal-output.txt**

```
gs://example-bucket/H20/AC0010001999B-01.jpg
gs://example-bucket/H20/AC0010001999B-02.jpg
gs://example-bucket/H20/AC0010001999B-03.jpg
```

I wrote this command, which doesn't seem to work in terminal (note: using macOS and zsh), but it checked out fine on https://sed.js.org (which I'm not expecting parity with *nix `sed` anyway):

```
sed -E 's;/(.+)/\1;/\1/;' input.txt > output.txt
```

If I check the regexp using `grep` (with minor modifications to escape forward slashes), seems to work fine:

```
cat input.txt | grep -E '\/(.+)\/\1'
```

[image: output of above command]

What extra specific crazy detail am I missing or not used properly?

Comment: Does it work with `..*` instead of `.+`?

Comment: That's strange. I just tested your example on my Centos box, and works perfectly!

Comment: Centos has a different `sed` implementation.

Comment: Meanwhile, I thought I'd be clever and have ChatGPT assist me, but it got hung up on the regexp and never produced workable results (although it was great for explaining the regexp). When asking it to update the regexp pattern because it didn't work, it made the regexp worse and worse.

Answer (score 0):

If the `H20` part is constant, I would personally use :

`sed -E 's_/H20/H20_/H20/_;' input.txt > output.txt`

Or can this part be totally random in your usecase ?

also, is it possible that the separation character `;` is messing up something with your terminal ?

Comment: I’ve tried with different delimiters and same results. Actually the pattern before I simplified to `(.*)` was `([AEHP]\d{2})` and then `([AEHP][0-9]{2})` since I was looking for a specific string pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The following's working with sed on my kali bash.
Does it work with sed on your Mac too?

```
sed 's/\/[AEHP][0-9]\{2\}/\//2g' input.txt > output.txt
```

It keeps intact the firs occurrence of the regexp `\/[AEHP][0-9]\{2\}` and replaces any others (`2g` directive = from the second onwards) with `/` char.